# Looking for Ubuntu Wily Werewolf's icon/insignia/clipart

Tags: unity, 15.10, desktop-background

I'm not finding a wallpaper that I like. I would like a wallpaper image with a purple-ish background (like the official wallpaper) and with the werewolf's head on it (the same one displayed during installation and on the t-shirt).

I'm not sure if there are any restrictions on the image because I can only find a few low res images containing the werewolf icon.

Can someone please point me to resources where I can find the werewolf icon in order for me to make my own wallpaper?

Comment: Google is your best bet here, there are many Wily wallpapers, with the purple theme https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ubuntu+wily+wallpapers&client=ubuntu&hs=ix8&channel=fs&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBqYeviJXKAhUMAxoKHXc8ARsQsAQIHw&biw=1366&bih=643

Comment: I've googled - a lot, before asking the question.  Google finds mostly the OS installation download

Comment: Click the link I gave you it is images only, no sites at all, there are many wallpapers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a downloadable .svg file of the [Werewolf Graphic here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Artwork/Official?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=werewolf_orange_hex.svg) on the [Ubuntu artwork page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Artwork/Official). There's a little orange download link just under the title of the image.

Comment: Artwork is the word I was missing ;)  Thank you for the link

Comment: I've made a very simple wallpaper. Available at http://www.ParanoidAndroid.co.za/